# awk for filtering a file with ~60 fields and >1500 entries

Tags: bash, awk, filter

I am trying to filter a file based on values of specific columns, ignoring the header line.

The command I tried:

```
awk '(NR = 1) || \
     (($7>=0.8) && ($13>-0.8) && ($19>=0.8) && \
      ($25>=0.8) && ($31>=0.8) && ($37>=0.8) && \
      ($39=3) && ($40=3))' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

When I run this, the resulting outfile.txt is exactly the same as infile.txt, even though I have checked that there are values in the infile.txt in columns 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, and 37 below 0.8, and likewise, values in column 39 and 40 below 3.

Could anyone please help me with a solution?

Thanks!!

ADip

Have included an example infile.txt with the first few lines of one of my files here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LuZenMuFYGekZwd1dpcks2Tkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add small part of your infile.txt?

Comment: Without looking at the input, I would change the first part to `NR==1`

Comment: Ooh. And change `($39=3) && ($40=3)` to `$39==3 && $40==3`

Comment: @MarcLambrichs thank you so much. That seems to have done the trick!!

Comment: Thanks @DharmaSaputra, have added a link to a few lines of the infile.txt ; following Marc Lambrichs's advice solved the problem though. Thank you!!

Comment: @MarcLambrichs – Please post that as an answer so ADip can accept it.

Comment: @ADip Converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being pressured to convert comment to answer. ;-)

Two mistakes you made in your awk will probably solve your problem:
Change `NR = 1` to `NR==1`
and
change `($39=3) && ($40=3)` to `$39==3 && $40==3`

Take-home message: there is a difference between assignment `=` and comparison `==`.